# Erro NaN no Calculo usando Javascript após click submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema aqui que não consigo resolver , nesse script a baixo realiza um calculo de sobre os assentos marcados, até aqui esta tudo perfeito o problema e quando eu coloco um botão submit para enviar os dados e acaba zerando o campo de resultado dando Erro de NaN. como posso corrigir isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
segue o javascript  https://jsfiddle.net/fabioo7/wjsdxLvk/

```
$(window).load(function(){
var contador = function() {
var n = $("input:enabled:checked").length;
var unchecked = 0;
var cb = $(this).index();
$("input:enabled").each(function(i) {
if ((i < cb) && !($(this).is(":checked"))) {
++unchecked;
}
}) 

if($(this).is(":checked")){
$('#campo').append('<div style="margin-top: 10px;"><input type="text"     placeholder="Insira seu Ticket" name="tks[]" required  class="created"    name="check1" ></div>');
}else{
$('.created').eq($(this).index()-unchecked).remove();
} 

$("#checkcount").text(n + (n === 1 ) + " Cadeiras Marcadas");
};
contador();
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", contador);


(function() {
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado_soma');
var resultadoInput = document.getElementById('resultado_soma2');
var checkCount = document.getElementById('checkcount2');

var total = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function() {
        if (this.checked === false) {
            total = total - this.value;
        } else {
            total = total + parseFloat(this.value);
        }

        resultado.innerHTML  = 'R$ ' + total.toFixed(2).replace(".",",");
        resultadoInput.value  = total.toFixed(2).replace(".",",");
        checkCount.value =  $("input:enabled:checked").length;
    }
}
})();

});
```

Comment: O que você exatamente quer fazer com essa função "Pagar"?

Comment: Tranquilo Samir.... E que na hora que vou salvar não vai nada no post pois da Erro NaN só de clicar no input submit

Answer (score 3):

Fiz algumas modificações. Olhe-as abaixo:

### 1.

O principal problema é que você está usando na maioria dos seletores para os `checkbox`, apenas `input`, sem especificar seu `type`. Por exemplo:

```
var n = $("input:enabled:checked").length;
```

Dessa maneira, você também seleciona as `input:text`, bem como as `input:submit`, o que não é o desejado, então substitua a linha acima por:

```
var n = $("input:checkbox:enabled:checked").length;
```

---

Faça também isso na linha do `each`, como está:

```
$("input:enabled").each(...
```

Como deveria estar:

```
$("input:checkbox:enabled").each(...
```

---

Já na área do Javascript Puro, a `var elements` está assim:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Deveria estar assim, utlizando o seletor `querySelectorAll`, como o filtro `[type='checkbox']`:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
```

---

E por último na `checkCount.value = $("input:enabled:checked").length`, que agora está assim:

```
checkCount.value =  $("input:checkbox:enabled:checked").length
```

### 2.

Para a captura do `index` dos elementos criados dinamicamente. Especifiquei dentro do `.index()`, como parâmetro, o `:checkbox`

```
$('.created').eq($(this).index(':checkbox')-unchecked).remove()
```

### 3.

Para que não seja permitido submeter o formulário sem que o tenha se escolhido ao menos uma opção, fiz essa função:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if($("input:checkbox:enabled:checked").length == 0){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

---

### [Demonstração - JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjsdxLvk/2/)

> Dica: é importante que ao invés da seleção dos elementos por seus *tagNames* você use um seletor por *class* ou *id*, assim não haverá problemas com a multiplicade das tags. :)

Comment: Show funcionou perfeitamente